# What window manager allows to customize the options menu of a window?

Tags: xfce, window-manager, openbox

Question's pretty simple. What window manager allows me to customize the window options menu (the menu that appears when you click the icon in the top left corner of a window)?

I've been checking and I'm afraid it's not straightforward. I've been checking the source code of xfwm (XFCE's window manager) and the creation of the options menu depends on the window flags set by the application, they're not read from a configuration file or anything else.

I'll check if openbox is configurable in that regard, but I have no hope. Do you know whether mwm or other (preferably lightweight) window manager allows for this?

Comment: What are you trying to customize via the "options menu of a window"?

Comment: I want to keep a few options (namely Always on top and close) and remove the rest.